# How do a query for a bridge longer or short than x?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Ist there a way to query for the length of a bridge in Overpass QL?

Bridges seem to come with the length argument, but maybe it's not widely in use?

```
["bridge:length"=100]
```

In addition, how can a query for a length longer or small than a given number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using some rarely used tag that isn't even documented on the OSM wiki, you should calculate the actual length of a way using `length()`. See this Help OSM post for some ideas: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325159/how-to-calculate-the-length-of-each-way-in-a-set-in-overpass-use-of-foreach-an

Working with numbers is described in this blog post: http://dev.overpass-api.de/blog/numbers.html

Comment: Thanks! I didn't make up the tag :-) just stumbled across it [here] (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:Key:bridge#Tags_die_in_diesem_Zusammenhang_gebraucht_werden) I am relatively new to it, so if there's is a better resource for tags, please let me know.

Comment: I'll dive into those links, but so it seems there is no simple way to query for "all bridges in area x which are longer than y meters"?

Comment: Well, yes, that's possible. Just start with *all* bridges in an area, then add the  (if:length() > xyz) as an additional filter criterion.